# Error in WHILE loop: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm new at PL/SQL. I want to display the country_id and country_name values from the COUNTRIES table for country_id whose values range from 51 through 55 using WHILE loop. The loop will finish in 55 and have displayed the 5 countries.

I get keep getting this error. I can't figure out what is wrong.

```
DECLARE
    v_country_id countries.country_id%TYPE;
    v_country_name countries.country_name%TYPE;
    v_counter NUMBER := 51;
BEGIN
    SELECT country_id, country_name INTO v_country_id, v_country_name
    FROM countries;

    WHILE v_counter <= 55 LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_counter ||' is : '|| v_country_id|| 'Country name is '||v_country_name);
        v_counter := v_counter+1;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: You have more than one country, so all of their ID's won't go into the single scalar `v_country_id` variable at once. That's what the error it reporting.

Comment: So how to display if the result more than one country? Wha's the syntax that I must use? I mean, If we want to retrieve data we must use SELECT statement. Sorry If I asking too much Sir. I'm new here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `v_country_id` and `v_country_name` variables can only hold a single value at a time, corresponding to one country. You are trying to select the values for all of your countries into those scalar variables as once, which is what is causing the error.

You can use [a cursor for-loop](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/cursor-FOR-LOOP-statement.html), where the cursor query selects the five countries you are interested in based on the ID range:

```
BEGIN
  FOR r_country IN (
    SELECT country_id, country_name
    FROM countries
    WHERE country_id BETWEEN 51 AND 55
    ORDER BY country_id
  )
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Country ' || r_country.country_id
      || ' is ' || r_country.country_name);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

You could also select into a collection comprising records with those fields, and loop over the collection to display the output - either filtering the rows when populating the collection, or as you loop over it.

Using `dbms_output` for anything except debugging isn't a good idea as it relies on the client being able to display that, which isn't always going to be the case.

You don't need PL/SQL for this of course, you can just run the cursor query on its own, but presumably this is an exercise...

```
SELECT 'Country ' || country_id || ' is ' || country_name
FROM countries
WHERE country_id BETWEEN 51 AND 55
ORDER BY country_id;
```

---

If you really want to use a while loop you can use an explicit cursor:

```
DECLARE
  v_country_id countries.country_id%TYPE;
  v_country_name countries.country_name%TYPE;
  v_counter PLS_INTEGER := 1;

  CURSOR c_country IS
    SELECT country_id, country_name
    FROM countries
    WHERE country_id >= 51
    ORDER BY country_id;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_country;
  WHILE v_counter <= 5
  LOOP
    FETCH c_country INTO v_country_id, v_country_name;
    -- in case there are fewer than 5 to display
    EXIT WHEN c_country%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_counter || ': '
      || 'Country ' || v_country_id || ' is ' || v_country_name);
    v_counter := v_counter + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Or you could use a collection:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_country_rec IS RECORD (
    country_id countries.country_id%TYPE,
    country_name countries.country_name%TYPE
  );
  TYPE t_country_tab IS TABLE OF t_country_rec;
  v_countries t_country_tab;
  v_counter PLS_INTEGER := 1;
BEGIN
  SELECT country_id, country_name
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_countries
  FROM countries
  WHERE country_id >= 51
  ORDER BY country_id;

  WHILE v_counter <= 5
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_counter || ': '
      || 'Country ' || v_countries(v_counter).country_id
      || ' is ' || v_countries(v_counter).country_name);
    v_counter := v_counter + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

You could use a `for` loop for either of those too, and could skip the filter in the query and do that in the loop instead.

But the implicit cursor for-loop is simpler.

---

> I haven't learn about 'cursor' in university

If you aren't supposed to use a cursor then maybe they want you to do a single-row query inside a loop, which is less efficient but closer to your original code; the `select ... into` moves *inside* the loop, but also gets a `where` clause to only get single row matching the current counter value:

```
DECLARE
  v_country_id countries.country_id%TYPE;
  v_country_name countries.country_name%TYPE;
  v_counter NUMBER := 51;
BEGIN
  WHILE v_counter <= 55 LOOP
    SELECT country_id,country_name INTO v_country_id, v_country_name
    FROM countries
    WHERE country_id = v_counter;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_counter ||' is : '|| v_country_id
      || ' Country name is '||v_country_name);

    v_counter := v_counter+1;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: If you are curious, why not try it? You'd need to use a collection for that though, or an explicit cursor loop.

Comment: Okay I got it.  Even I haven't learn about 'cursor' in university but, I'm tying my best to understand it. Thank you Sir for your help. It helps me :))

Comment: @MayaRetnosari - ok, added a version that doesn't use a cursor, but does individual single-row queries inside a while loop. Does that look like what you're expected to be able to do at the moment?

Comment: Okay, yeah finally I just got it. I got the result as I want (without use a cursor) by use FOR and WHILE. Thank you for your help and explanations.  It really helps me a lot. :))